# jQuery animation with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed animated banner to show and hide div's with delayed animation, but at the end of the animation all things are still triggered together and timing is ignored and events are not fired correctly. Didn't find anywhere what could be wrong with my code, any suggestions how to handle this thins better?
Heres the HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="background">
<img class="background-image" src="img/ev200-background.png">
  <div class="txt-1">
    <img src="img/ev200-txt-1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="txt-2">
    <span class="ship">
    <img src="img/ev200-ship.png">
    </span>
    <span class="txt-in-1">
      <img src="img/ev200-txt-2.png">
      </span>
    <span class="txt-in-2">
      <img src ="img/ev200-txt-3.png">
      </span>
    </div>

  <div class="txt-3">
    <span class="txt-in-3-1">
        <img src="img/ev200-txt-4.png">
      </span>
    <span class="west-tooder">
      <img src="img/ev200-W-icon.png">
      </span>
    </div>

    <div class="txt-4">
      <span class="txt-4-description">
        <img src="img/ev200-txt-5.png">
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="txt-5">
        <span class="txt-5-description">
          <img src="img/ev200-txt-6.png">
          </span>
        </div>

        <div class="txt-6">
          <span class="txt-6-description">
            <img src="img/ev200-txt-7.png">
            </span>
          </div>


</div> <!-- End of background-->



</div>
```

And here's jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

$( ".container" ).click(function() {

```
$( ".txt-1" ).animate({
  top: "120px",
  left: "160",
  right: "0",
  }, 1500, function() {

});

$( ".txt-1 img" ).animate({
  width: "80%",
  height: "auto"
}, 1500, function() {

});

  $( ".txt-1" ).animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-2" ).delay(3000).animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".ship" ).delay(4500).animate({
    height: "80%",
    top: "10%",
    left: "5%"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-2 .txt-in-1" ).delay(4500).animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 750, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-2 .txt-in-2" ).delay(5250).animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, 750, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-2" ).delay(6000).animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 750, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-3" ).delay(6000).animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-3" ).delay(7500).animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-4" ).delay(9000).animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-4" ).delay(10500).animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-5" ).delay(12000).animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-5" ).delay(13500).animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-6" ).delay(15000).animate({
    opacity: "1"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });

  $( ".txt-6" ).delay(16500).animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, 1500, function() {

  });
```

});

});

Comment: Why all the empty callbacks? Also can I see your HTML? Also do you know that by using `delay()` *and* the delay as a parameter in `animate()` you are effectively increasing the time? Why not consolidate?

Comment: Edited my text and added HTML. Didn't add callback functions because didn't know why. Which should be correct example considered that i want to have different delays and animation times?

Comment: Ok. can you also post your CSS?

Comment: Your animations are working fine. are you sure you are linking to your javascript file correctly?